# Not able to pass special character into request

Tags: iphone, json

When I try to make request with some special character like japanese , then request is going to break and i am not able to get result. so my question is, how to pass special character in other language into request ?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Firstly, by providing some context and code, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

You should encode your characters to UTF8 like this

```
NSString *encodedURL = [oldUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: I would also do the same thing.